# Virtual Threads в Spring Webflux

Tags: многопоточность, spring-boot, производительность, reactive, webflux

Недавно вышла Java 21 в которой добавили виртуальные потоки, я смотрел некоторые тесты производительности Spring boot на виртуальных потоках и Spring WebFlux по результатам было видно что стандартный Spring boot превосходит реактивный Spring webflux, у меня вопрос есть ли смысл использовать виртуальные потоки в Spring WebFlux для повышения производительности? Будет ли прирост производительности? Не будет ли это блокирующей операцией?
Так же как использовать виртуальные потоки в Spring WebFlux? Является ли мой код ниже хорошей практикой

```
private final ExecutorService virtualPool;

public Mono<String> myMethod() {
    return Mono.fromFuture(CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> doBlockOperation(), virtualPool));
}
```